# Git branches won't automatically change in VS Code when I 'git checkout' to a different branch. Can this be fixed?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-branch

I have to close and reopen VS Code for it to switch branches. Not sure why it is doing this, it is updated to latest version as well.